# Proof only three types of hexagonal, convex monohedral tessellations

Tags: geometry, reference-request, polygons, tessellations

Where can I get a proof that there exist exactly three types of convex, hexagonal, monohedral tessellations of the plane?

I'm already aware of Reinhardt thesis and Bollobás paper (1963). I was wondering if other (more direct) proofs are available in the literature

Comment: Could you give some references to Reinhardt and/or Bollobas ?

Comment: B. Bollobas, Filling the plane with congruent convex hexagons without overlapping. Ann. Univ. Sci. Budapest. Eotvos Sect. Math. 6 (1963) 
K. Reinhardt, Uber die Zerlegung der Ebene in Polygone, Dissertation, Universitat Frankfurt am Main, (1918)

Comment: Thanks for the references.